# How can use client id selector along with another selector in jquery

Tags: jquery

To get the `client id` of control i have used selector in this way which is right

```
$("#" + "<%=Alloption.ClientID%>")
```

Now i want to use `Client id followed by td` as shown, how can i use Selector to get the client id of `DisplayTable` followed by `td`

```
$('#DisplayTable td')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I *think* you mean this:

```
$("#<%=Alloption.ClientID%> td")
```

This will select all `td` elements within the element identified by `Alloption.ClientID`.

Note that you don't need to do `"#"` and `"<%=Alloption.ClientID%>"` as separate strings.

Answer (score 1):

You can simply do this :

```
$("#<%=Alloption.ClientID%> td")
```

Note that I removed the first string concatenation : it's useless as well.